# rails 3 default_scope(:where) and find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Find doesn't descope the `default_scope` anymore, what should I do now? I need to find entries that are out of the default scope on so many places and I also need the scoped arrays of entries for so many lists in my application.

Why did they changed it? :(

Comment: Have you tried [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class)? Btw, if there are many places that you need record outside of default scope may be it's no longer such a good default scope.

Comment: ye it removes stuff like order also, which i need always. i really dont understand why they drop `except` or is it just a bug? because the method is still there, it's just not doing anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article as what has been deprecated in Rails3 [here](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface).

So if you want to use the model without the default_scope on it, then you can use the following as in the snippet below.(This is extracted from the article I mentioned)

**with_scope and with_exclusive_scope**

with_scope and with_exclusive_scope are now implemented on top of Relation as well. Making it possible to use any relation with them :

```
with_scope(where(:name => 'lifo')) do
  ...
end
```

Or even use a named scope :

```
with_exclusive_scope(Item.red) do
  ...
end
```